# Parse Dataframe and store output in a single file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame using Spark SQL in Scala with columns A and B with values:

```
A | B
1 a|b|c
2 b|d
3 d|e|f
```

I need to store the output to a single textfile in following format

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 b
2 d
3 d
3 e
3 f
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired Dataframe with an expode and a split:

```
val resultDF = df.withColumn("B", explode(split($"B", "\\|")))
```

**Result**

```
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  1|  b|
|  1|  c|
|  2|  b|
|  2|  d|
|  3|  d|
|  3|  e|
|  3|  f|
+---+---+
```

Then you can save in a single file with a coalesce(1)

```
  resultDF.coalesce(1).rdd.saveAsTextFile("desiredPath")
```

Comment: explode function is not recognized in my code. What dependency do I need to add?

Comment: this should be enough: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
val df = ???
val resDF =df.withColumn("B", explode(split(col("B"), "\\|")))

resDF.coalesce(1).write.option("delimiter", " ").csv("path/to/file")
```

Comment: explode(split(col : this part of your code is not recognized

Comment: `col` comes from org.apache.spark.sql.functions